# Define coordinates with rotation (corona sdk)

Tags: coronasdk

I already asked my question, someone answered me but even with the answer I can't find.
So here is my problem, I'm making a shooter based game, my shooter is the circle in the middle. I can easily rotate it, by touching on the screen, and with some maths, the shooter is showing at the point where I touched. (with event.x and event.y.

And I want to shoot the bullets to that direction that my shooter is showing. I know the coordinates of my shooter and I know the shooters rotation.

And the answer was to use trigonometry, the problem is, how do I use trigonometry to find my coordinates?

I want to use the transition function, for that I need these coordinates. If someone knows about an another way to make the bullet travel without those coordinates and/or the transition function, it would be adorable!
Thanks in advance,
Fannick!


[Image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Hi2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So he it is! :) From an object in the middle, with the rotation of the object in degrees, it will define where the bullet will be shot with the transition to, note that "c" is the shooter, "h" the display.contentHeight and "w" the display.contentWidth. I also defined bulletX and bulletY as the second possition of the bullet.

```
    if c.rotation <= math.deg(math.atan((h/2)/(w/2))) and c.rotation >= 0 then
    bulletX = w
    bulletY = h/2 + w/2 * math.tan( (c.rotation * math.pi)/180 )

elseif c.rotation > math.tan(math.rad((h/2)/(w/2))) and c.rotation <= 90 then

    bulletX = w/2 + math.tan( (90 * math.pi) / 180  - (c.rotation * math.pi ) / 180) * h/2
    bulletY = h

elseif c.rotation > 90 and c.rotation <= 90 + math.deg( math.atan( (w/2) / (h/2) ) ) then

    bulletX = w/2 - math.tan( ((c.rotation * math.pi)/180) - ((90 * math.pi) / 180)) * h/2 
    bulletY = h

elseif c.rotation > 90 + math.deg( math.atan( (w/2) / (h/2) ) ) and c.rotation <= 180 then
    bulletX = 0
    bulletY = h/2 + math.tan( math.pi - ((c.rotation*math.pi) / 180)) * w/2

elseif c.rotation > 180 and c.rotation <= 180 + math.deg( math.atan ((h/2)/(w/2))) then
    bulletX = 0
    bulletY = h/2 - math.tan( ((c.rotation * math.pi)/180) - math.pi) * w/2

elseif c.rotation > 180 + math.deg( math.atan ((h/2)/(w/2))) and c.rotation <= 270 then
    bulletX = w/2 - math.tan( ((270 * math.pi) / 180) - ((c.rotation * math.pi) / 180)) * h/2
    bulletY = 0

elseif c.rotation > 270 and c.rotation <= 270 + math.deg(math.atan((w/2)/(h/2))) then
    bulletX = w/2 + math.tan( ((c.rotation * math.pi)/180) - ((270 * math.pi)/180)) * h/2
    bulletY = 0

elseif c.rotation > 270 + math.deg(math.atan((w/2)/(h/2))) and c.rotation <= 360 then
    bulletX = w
    bulletY = h/2 - math.tan( ((360 * math.pi)/180) - ((c.rotation * math.pi) / 180) ) * w/2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not ideal but maybe it can help you to learn more about CoronaSDK and what are you trying to do.

```
local touchedX -- the X coordinate of the touch
local touchedY -- the Y coordinate of the touch
local shooterX -- the X coordinate of the shooter
local shooterY -- the Y coordinate of the shooter

local bullet = display.newImage( "bullet.png") -- the image for the bullet
bullet.x = shooterX
bullet.y = shooterY

--this is what is going to move the bullet from the shooter to the place you touched
transition.to( bullet, {time = 100, x = touchedX, y = touchedY} )
```

Comment: Thank you so much Fayer for your quick answer! I found another way to do it, again with trigonometry, I will post the answer! Your idea also works, but sometimes it could lag for me because of my button, if I touch the shoot button it will update the event coordinates to the one of the shoot button, but if I would use a joystick and not the full screen it would work for sure! Thanks alot!

Comment: You are weolcome! Remember, the way to thank people is to upvote their answer :)

Comment: Yeah I know it, I wanted to upvote your answer but apparently I need 15 thingy to do it 0.o

Answer (score 0):

> **EDIT:** I've found why I don't find the same solution as my calculator, math.tan is only working with radians! That's why it gave me some totally random-looking values. I'll share you the code once I'm done!

So this is the code I've found, I used a screen of 200pi by 200pi to make an example, 
"c" is my shooter, and it's in the middle of the screen, so c.x = 100 and c.y = 100. As said over I can turn the shooter with an event.

```
if c.rotation <= 45 and c.rotation >= 0 then
    bulletX = 200
    bulletY = 100 + math.tan( c.rotation ) * 100
end
if c.rotation > 45 and c.rotation <= 90 then
    bulletX = 100 + math.tan( 90 - c.rotation ) * 100
    bulletY = 200
end
    if c.rotation > 90 and c.rotation <= 135 then
    bulletX = 100 - math.tan( c.rotation - 90 ) * 100
    bulletY = 200
end
    if c.rotation > 135 and c.rotation <= 180 then
    bulletX = 0
    bulletY = 100 + math.tan( 180 - c.rotation ) * 100
end
    if c.rotation > 180 and c.rotation <= 225 then
    bulletX = 0
    bulletY = 100 - math.tan( c.rotation - 180 ) * 100
end
    if c.rotation > 225 and c.rotation <= 270 then
    bulletX = 100 - math.tan( 270 - c.rotation ) * 100
    bulletY = 0
end
    if c.rotation > 270 and c.rotation <= 315 then
    bulletX = 100 + math.tan( c.rotation - 270 ) * 100
    bulletY = 200
end
    if c.rotation > 315 and c.rotation <= 360 then
    bulletX = 200
    bulletY = 100 - math.tan( 360 - c.rotation ) * 100
end
```

The code is actually perfectly working if I do it with my calculator.
But, I don't why but corona sdk hasn't the same results...
Does anyone has an idea why?

Comment: Oh! My fault! I've found the problem, math.tan only works with angle in radians! :) I'll share you the final code :)